# what's the difference b/t "svn <cmd> -r <rev> TARGET" and "svn <cmd> TARGET@<rev>"

Tags: svn

what's the difference between "svn < cmd> -r < rev> TARGET" and "svn < cmd> TARGET@< rev>"?
Am getting two different answers for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two different types are called *peg* and *operative revisions*, and they can also be used together:

```
svn command -r OPERATIVE-REV item@PEG-REV
```

That means: The command operates on revision *OPERATIVE-REV* of the path found under the name *item* in revision *PEG-REV*. If you use only the *OPERATIVE-REV*, the *PEG-REV* defaults to *BASE* for working copies and *HEAD* for repository URLs. If you only specify the *PEG-REV*, the same revision is used as *OPERATIVE-REV*.

You can find a detailed explanation in the online book *Version Control with Subversion* in the following section:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html